# .bundle gets its private framework removed if it is bundled inside of a Cocoa App

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, build-process

I have a Cocoa App, which has a .bundle in its Resources. Both the app and the bundle have the same private framework. Each of them includes its own copy.

Everything is set up in a Xcode Workspace. There are three projects in this workspace, the Framework, the Bundle and the Cocoa App. The Framework is referenced from the built directory, it is copied with a "Copy Files (to Frameworks)" phase to the Build Phases of each target.

When I compile the bundle and inspect the product I can see the Framework. If I inspect the compiled app I can see the framework and the bundle.

When run, the separately compiled bundle and the app work as expected, so my way of adding the private framework works.

The problem is with the bundle that sits inside the app. It does not contain the framework. And because of this it can't be run.

[image]

Does anybody know what happens here? And how to fix it?

Right now I'm compiling the bundle separately and replace the one in the app by hand.

Answer (score 0):

as often I discovered the answer just minutes after I posted the question.

I could fix the problem by two simple steps:

1. Add new "Copy Files" build phase with Resources Destination for the .bundle
2. Remove the .bundle from "Copy Bundle Resources" phase

Still not sure if this is a bug, or if there is reason behind this behavior.

Comment: I figured out that the "Copy Bundle Resources" phase removed all resources the bundle had.